# Merge 2 Binary Heaps

Tags: data-structures, heaps

I want to merge $2$ binary heaps. Which is the fastest algorithm to do so. Also would like to know its time complexity.

I know how to do it linear time $O(n)$, I want to know if there is something faster (probably there is).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72600/best-way-to-merge-2-max-heaps-into-a-min-heap

Comment: This is a question &  answers site, not an algorithms archive.

Comment: Why would you expect an algorithm in $o(n)$ time? That would mean that can only look at very few nodes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67440/discussion-between-ryan-and-raphael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to merge two standard binary heaps in $\mathcal O(\log n)$ time, picking $\pm\infty$ setting the both heaps as children and then extracting top element (this operation takes $\mathcal O(\log n)$ time).

You might be also interested in paper about [faster merge in $\log k * \log n$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00264229), but it is non-standard, pointer based implementation. The standard approach is to use array. The other operations take a bit longer though.

Another idea is to use Binomial heap or Leftist heap, with merge operation in $\mathcal O(\log n)$ time or Fibonacci, Pairing, Brodal or Rank-pairing heap to support merge in $\Theta(1)$ time.

The list is described at Wikipedia, [Binomial heap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap). Although marvelous at first glance they hide larger constant and increase time of standard operations on heaps, for example find min may be $\mathcal O(\log n)$ instead of $\Theta(1)$.

If you want the asymptoticaly fastest algorithm then any of mentioned are good. For practical purposes I would recommend the Pairing heap, which is a form of multiway tree, easy to implement (comparing with Brodal for example).

Comment: I don't care about the copies. Lets say theorically we don't copy anything, Can you give me the fastest algoritm

Comment: I don't think this answer hits the mark; we may be able to link the two heaps (in tree representation) together without inspecting every node. (Not that I think it's likely, but the argument is not solid on its own.)

Comment: The first paragraph ignores that the two binary heaps might have different heights, and that joining them with a dummy root can lead to a non-balanced (non-complete) binary tree.